# how to make div borders slant?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs which stands as my background color, I wanted to to have slanted bottom borders just like this:
this: http://onepagelove.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/opl-big36.jpg

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body { height: 200%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }


#first {
top: 0;
background-color: orange;
 height: 50%;
}

#second {
bottom: 0;
background-color: green;
 height: 50%;
}

#third {
top: 0;
background-color: blue;
 height: 50%;
}

#fourth {
bottom: 0;
background-color: red;
 height: 50%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="first">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="second">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="third">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="fourth">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post some code showing what you've tried.

Comment: Multiple divs with multiple bg colors and css

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it haha! Thanks for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want a grid like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). You will want like:

```
<div class="row" id="firstBackground">
    <!-- Contents... -->
</div>

<div class="row" id="secondBackground">
    <!-- Contents... -->
</div>

<div class="row" id="thirdBackground">
    <!-- Contents... -->
</div>

<div class="row" id="forthBackground">
    <!-- Contents... -->
</div>
```

I hope it helps.